# How do I add additional syntax highlighting/coloring to my Text Editor

Tags: python, syntax-highlighting, textwrangler

So I'm using *TextWrangler4.5.3* and primarily *Python* for scripting. When I write Python, I often like to make comments that say something like: `# BEGINS foo` and then later `# ENDS foo`  I do this so, **later** editing and understanding is quick and clear. Finally getting to the point: i want to tell *TextWrangler* to make "`# BEGINS`" a different coler, say.. green.

Thanks SO much in advance for any insight =P

Answer (score 5):

If you want to use a different color scheme than the factory defaults, go to `Preferences`->`Text Colors`. I would suggest creating a new theme, with green comments.

[image: Python Color Scheme]

Next, go to `Preferences`->`Languages` and create a Custom Language Preference for Python.

[image: New Python Language entry]

Within the 'Display' tab of this language preference window, change the color scheme to the new one created earlier.

[image: Python color scheme]

I'm not aware of a way to make some comments, such as `"""` vs `'''` vs `#`, differ in color (it's probably a global "anything that is a comment will have the same theme" for TextWrangler).

Is this what you are trying to do?